Why is the lift of a foliate vector field to the transverse bundle a foliate vector field w.r.t. the lifted foliation?
Let $M$ be a manifold with a foliation $F$ of codimension $q$, and let $p: B \rightarrow M$ be the transverse frame bundle (which over each point of $M$ consists of frames in the quotient of the tangent space of $M$ by the distribution at that point).
Let $X \in \Gamma(TM)$ be a foliate vector field, which is equivalent to the fact that its flows invariate the distribution of vectors tangent to $F$.
If $\phi_t$ is the flow of $X$ at time $t$, a local diffeomorphism of $M$, then we define a local diffeomorphism of $B$ as follows: if $\phi_t$ is defined at $x \in M$ and $z \in B_x$ is a transverse frame over $x$, we see $z$ as the linear isomorphism $z: \mathbb R^q \rightarrow T_x M/ T_x F$ and we set
$$
B(\phi_t)(z):= (\phi_t)_* \circ z: \mathbb R^q \rightarrow T_{\phi_t(x)} M / T_{\phi_t(x)} F
$$
$B(\phi_t)(z)$ is well defined because $(\phi_t)_*$ invariates the distribution associated to $F$; we thus have a $1$-parameter group on $B$, so a vector field.
I am trying to see why if $\phi_t$ invariate the distribution of $F$, then $B(\phi_t)$ invariate the distribution of the lifted foliation. The distribution of the lifted foliation can be defined as locally being $\ker (\pi_T)_* $ where $\pi_T$ is the projection to a local quotient manifold in a foliated chart - actually, the lift of that projection to a projection between the transverse bundle and the frame bundle of the local quotient manifold.
So I need to see that for $Y$ a vector field tangent to $B$, if $\pi_{T,*} (Y) = 0$, then $\pi_{T,*}( B(\phi_t)_* Y) = 0$.
What I tried:
Taking the flow of $Y$ at time $s$ to be $\alpha_s$, we know that $\pi_T(\alpha_s(z) )$ is constant in $s$ for fixed $z$. So if we could prove that
$$
\pi_T( B(\phi_t)(\alpha_s(z)) )
=
\pi_T( \alpha_s(B(\phi_t)(z)) )
$$
we would be done. I can't see how to make progress from here, however. In particular, I can't see how to use the fact that $X$ is foliate or whether that is needed further (it might not be needed further, because this fact was essential to define $B(\phi_t)$, not every local diffeomorphism admits a lift to the transverse bundle).
